# Using Jersy 2.19, I cannot find what is wrong, I'm always having 404

Tags: rest, http-status-code-404, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to create a Jersey 2 based project.
The project will expose one service which returns json.
But when launching the app, I'm still having 404 not found error and I can't find out what's wrong.

Since I'm using Mave, here's my pom :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <groupId>com</groupId>
        <artifactId>test.jersey</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- Jersey -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <!-- <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>-->
                    </configuration>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Here's my web.xml :

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.jersey</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And here's my implementation of a service :

```
package com.test.jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Path("/test")
public class Test{

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map<String, String> getVersions() throws FileNotFoundException {

        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
        response.put("I wonder", "If it works");

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: When calling the service, I'm calling http://localhost:8080/jersey/test (jersey is the context path defined in my tomcat server)

Answer (score 0):

You have the dependencies as `provided`. That is saying that Tomcat has the jars, which it doesn't. Just remove the `<scope>provided</scope>`

You can also take out these (they are pulled in by the `jersey-container-servlet`)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
```